# How to deploy docker containers on permise

Tags: docker, deployment

I work for a company where we are developing a web application of about 20 microservices between FE and BE. The company wants to deploy the containers in its local infrastucture based on wmvare. Knowing that we expect to have maximum 40/50 connected users at the same time, how do you suggest to deploy the containers? In which enviroment? We checked to use the container functionalities of wmvare but to do that we should change same network configuration of all the active vm in production and the person in charge is not confident in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

- security-wise it is good to have your server on separate virtual machine. In this case you retain snapshot and migration functionality as long with host isolation;
- Inside guest virtual machine you can use Docker containers. It allows you to deploy and maintain your application with relatively small effort. As platform I'd use [Ubuntu server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server) or [RHEL](https://www.redhat.com/en). On Ubuntu it is better to [use latest](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) docker repository, so it will have containerd management daemon.

It is hard to give more accurate instructions without knowledge of network topology, but maybe you consider routing so you do not need to change your network configuration.